# ReactiveCocoa- How to dispose of a signal using 'switchToLatest'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a UITableViewCell with a viewModel property. As the tableview cell is getting reused I would like it to bind to properties of its *latest* viewModel, like so:

```
RAC(self.titleLabel, text) =
[[RACObserve(self, viewModel) map:^id(MyViewModel *viewModel) {
    return RACObserve(viewModel, title);
}]
switchToLatest];
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the cell is never getting released when it should be. 
Is there a way to dispose of the signal when the cell should be dealloc-ed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake! `RACObserve()` will retain self– I was missing a `@strongify(self)`.
Solved with:

```
@weakify(self);
RAC(self.titleLabel, text) =
[[RACObserve(self, viewModel) map:^id(MyViewModel *viewModel) {
   @strongify(self);
   return RACObserve(viewModel, title);
}]
switchToLatest];
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me add that there's a more concise way of writing that. Assuming you're using storyboards or xibs for your cells:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    RAC(self, textLabel.text) = RACObserve(self, viewModel.title);
}
```